# Replacing all periods in a string does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string, replace

I am performing a regular expression in JavaScript to replace the periods that don't come after numbers or before a pound symbol with 4's. When I enter `i.t.` as input, it converts it to 'i4t.' Why is this occurring?

The pattern I have is

```
RegExp('([^\\d])[.]([^#])', "g")
```

Example Input: `i.t.`
Expected Output: `i4t4`
Actual Output: `i4t.`

Comment: provide example input strings and desired output you wanna get

Comment: I think you may use `s.replace(/(^|\D)\.(?!#)/g, '$14')`

Comment: `"i.t.".replace(/\./g,4);` - this is ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[^#]` negated character class matches and consumes the char that is not a `#`. The dot after `t` is thus matched during the first iteration, and the second match does not occur.

You may use

```
s.replace(/(^|\D)\.(?!#)/g, '$14')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PujXou/1).

**Details**

- `(^|\D)` - Capturing group 1: either start of a string (`^`) or (`|`) any char other than a digit (`\D`) (**NOTE**: If the `.` at the start of the string should not be touched, use `(\D)`)
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?!#)` - no `#` allowed immediately to the right of the current location.

JS demo:

```js
console.log(
  "i.t.".replace(/(^|\D)\.(?!#)/g, '$14')
);
```

Comment: I added the end of your regex where it matches the '.' only if it is not followed by a '#' to the regex I had above and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @jim-asg Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) as you are entitled to the upvoting privilege after reaching 15 rep points. Note you may upvote all the answers that turned out helpful.